# Escape [square brackets] in Jade to prevent conflict with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, syntax-error, pug, conflict

AngularJS uses square brackets for parameters to its directives
([input[number]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D))

but [Jade also uses square brackets for class attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#classattribs).

So this doesn't work

```
input(type='number' [name='amount'] [min='min'] [max='max'])
```

> Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined

Is there a way to escape square brackets in Jade?

Comment: avoid brackets and use: input(type='number', name='amount', min='min', max='max')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets from angular's documentation indicate that the attribute is optional, but the square brackets should **not** be used in html itself.

This example:

```
 <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="value"
                 min="0" max="99" required>
```

is from angular's documentation and it does not use any square brackets.